# WSO2 ESB Xsd mapping tool

Tags: xsd, wso2, wso2-esb

Why WSO2 ESB is not providing any ***XSD to XSD*** or WSDL mapping tool? 
I am from TIBCO background, working now a days on WSO2 platform. Please give your feedback on my question.

Comment: Not sure whether we have this kind of facility in WSO2 as of now. Need to explore Developer studio for it.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK if we want to make one data format to another we can use xslt mediator.

Comment: WSO2 supports XQuery and Javascript as well to achieve transformation.

Answer (score -1):

you should use the validate mediator to check your incoming request against a xsd.
sample below:

```
<validate source="//RequestParentNode">
                        <schema key="conf:/sampleXSD.xml"/>
                        <on-fail>
                            <log level="custom">
                                <property name="MESSAGE" expression="get-property('ERROR_MESSAGE')"/>
                            </log>
                            <makefault version="soap11">
                                <code xmlns:soap11Env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" value="soap11Env:VersionMismatch"/>
                                <reason expression="get-property('ERROR_MESSAGE')"/>
                            </makefault>
                            <send/>
                        </on-fail>
                    </validate>
```

Comment: Hi Rohan, question is not for validating an XML document against XSD. He is asking whehter WSO2 provides any XQuery/transformation mapper kind of tool to generate target xml.